# Mixing :include and :joins in ActiveRecord query with nested associations

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was wondering if and how one could achieve mixing `:include` and `:joins` in associations to avoid needless roundtrips when retrieving an object from the database.

For instance, when having a model space like:

```
 —————                —————             —————
|  A  | 0..1 ————— * |  B  | * ————— 1 |  C  |
 —————                —————             —————
```

Here I'm loading an instance of A by a known identifier to display in my view, but I would like to load B and C as well (B via `:include`, and C via `:joins`). Can this be done? So far, I am using `:include` only, ie.

```
A.find params[:id], :include => [ { :b => :c } ]
```

which naturally generates two additional roundtrips (1., fetch A by id, 2. fetch associated Bs, 3. fetch associated Cs).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Rails 3, you can just chain such methods.

```
A.includes(:b).joins(b: :c).find(params[:id])
```